# QuickBooks Query - Deposit Query

Tags: c#, xml, quickbooks

I'm new to Quickbooks integration with C# and I'm running the following code to request a DepositQuery with a specific time range as following:

```
string DepositQueryRq = @"<?xml version =""1.0""   encoding=""utf-8""?>
             <?qbxml version=""2.0""?>
            <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError = ""stopOnError"">
            <DepositQueryRq requestID = ""[reqID]"" />   
            <TxnDateRangeFilter>
            <FromTxnDate>2018-03-14</FromTxnDate>          
            </TxnDateRangeFilter>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>".Replace("[reqID]", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"));
string res = RequestHandler.Process(DepositQueryRq);
```

and it returns the following message:
QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

and i'm running the same query but without the Date specifier and it returns the list of all the Desposits

```
string DepositQueryRq = @"<?xml version =""1.0""   encoding=""utf-8""?>
         <?qbxml version=""2.0""?>
        <QBXML>
        <QBXMLMsgsRq onError = ""stopOnError"">
        <DepositQueryRq requestID = ""[reqID]"" />               
        </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>".Replace("[reqID]", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"));
   string res = RequestHandler.Process(DepositQueryRq);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the TimeFilter in the Query's body like this:

```
string DepositQueryRq = @"<?xml version =""1.0""   encoding=""utf-8""?>
             <?qbxml version=""2.0""?>
            <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError = ""stopOnError"">
            <DepositQueryRq requestID = ""[reqID]"">              
            <TxnDateRangeFilter>
            <FromTxnDate>2018-03-14</FromTxnDate> 
            <ToTxnDate>2018-03-28</ToTxnDate>
            </TxnDateRangeFilter>
            </DepositQueryRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>".Replace("[reqID]", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"));
```

OR

```
string DepositQueryRq = @"<?xml version =""1.0""   encoding=""utf-8""?>
             <?qbxml version=""2.0""?>
            <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError = ""stopOnError"">
            <DepositQueryRq requestID = ""[reqID]"">   
            <ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
            <FromModifiedDate>2018-03-13T10</FromModifiedDate>
            <ToModifiedDate>2018-03-28T5</ToModifiedDate>
            </ModifiedDateRangeFilter>           
            </DepositQueryRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
            </QBXML>".Replace("[reqID]", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"));
```